# Winform Add Many Row Dynamically in TableLayoutPanel Can't Show Up

Tags: vb.net, winforms, row, tablelayout

As picture (UI Designer), I put a Tablelayoutpanel in a panel 
and dynamically add buttons in a row.

When the row count exceeds a certain number, the buttons do not show.
If I click "tab", I can't select the button.

UI Designer

[image]

```
tblLayout.Controls.Clear()
tblLayout.RowStyles.Clear()
tblLayout.ColumnStyles.Clear()
tblLayout.SuspendLayout()

''Tbl_Data: Search Data ( I want to show some information for button)
For i As Integer = 0 To Tbl_Data.Rows.Count - 1
  Dim tmpBtn As Button = New Button()
  tmpBtn.Text = "test"
  tmpBtn.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
  tmpBtn.Padding = New Padding(0, 0, 0, 0)
  tmpBtn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat         
  tmpBtn.Font = New Font("Consolas", 15)
  AddHandler tmpBtn.Click, AddressOf Me.u_Click

  tblLayout.RowStyles.Add(New RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 80.0F))
  tblLayout.Controls.Add(tmpBtn)
  tblLayout.RowCount += 1
 Next
 tblLayout_Coil.ResumeLayout()
```

Result

[image]

I found a weird thing.
When I change the `RowStyle` to 40F it does show more row lines.
But still there is some upper limit.

Comment: This may be a shot in the dark, but I have read somewhere the `RowCount` should be in sync with the number of `RowStyles`, which is what you apparently do. However, the order of things might not be correct. Try increasing the RowCount first `tblLayout.RowCount += 1`, then add the new style `tblLayout.RowStyles.Add(New RowStyle(SizeType.Absolute, 80.0F))` and finally add the button `tblLayout.Controls.Add(tmpBtn)`

Comment: I tried to do you say. But it still have same problem.I don't know why it cause.